# creating a responsive skewed background with css

Tags: html, css, background, skew

I'm trying to create a skewed background on my website. The blocks will all have a skewed top and bottom line (like a parallelogram).

[design example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4vLl.png)

Tried using css:

```
transform: skewY(-30deg);
```

but it's not working responsively. Any thoughts on a good practice?

Comment: @LGSon would that second option work with multiple areas?

Comment: You can add more stops

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a start, both very lightweight

Using a pseudo element

```
.wrapper div.skew::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120vw;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-30deg) skew(-30deg);
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper div.skew::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120vw;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-30deg) skew(-30deg);
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="skew">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div>
    Some text
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Using `linear-gradient`

```
html {
    background: linear-gradient(
                 -30deg, 
                 transparent 40%,
                 #bbb 40%,
                 #bbb 60%,
                 transparent 60%);
}
```

```css
html {
    background: linear-gradient(
                 -30deg, 
                 transparent 40%,
                 #bbb 40%,
                 #bbb 60%,
                 transparent 60%);
}
div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
Some text
</div>
<div class="skew">
Some text
</div>
<div>
Some text
</div>
```

Comment: using your first option makes the background parallelogram, but it's not reaching the sides. Any ideas?

Comment: @mas My intention were to show a how-to, not a full setup, still, updated first option

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not quite there yet but it's getting pretty close. The use of "vw" and "translate" made the difference!

Answer (score 1):

I really like the css generated content method of Jeremy Frank - he even provides a cool SASS-Mixin in his article:
https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms

I use this variation alot:

```
/*
 * Angled-edges
 */

@mixin angle($pseudo, $flip: false, $use-background-color: false, $angle: 3deg) {
  // $pseudo: before, after, both
  @if $pseudo == 'before' or $pseudo == 'after' or $pseudo == 'both' {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    $selector: if($pseudo == 'both', '&:before,&:after', '&:#{$pseudo}');

    #{$selector} {
      @if $use-background-color {
        background: $color__background-body;
      } @else {
        background: inherit;
      }
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 50%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    @if $pseudo == 'before' {
      #{$selector} {
        top: 0;

        @if $flip {
          transform: skewY($angle * -1);
          transform-origin: 0 0;
        } @else {
          transform: skewY($angle);
          transform-origin: 100% 0;
        }
      }
    }

    @if $pseudo == 'after' {
      #{$selector} {
        bottom: 0;

        @if $flip {
          transform: skewY($angle);
          transform-origin: 0 100%;
        } @else {
          transform: skewY($angle * -1);
          transform-origin: 100%;
        }
      }
    }

    @if $pseudo == 'both' {
      &:before {
        top: 0;

        @if $flip {
          transform: skewY($angle * -1);
          transform-origin: 0 0;
        } @else {
          transform: skewY($angle);
          transform-origin: 100% 0;
        }
      }

      &:after {
        bottom: 0;

        @if $flip {
          transform: skewY($angle);
          transform-origin: 0 0;
        } @else {
          transform: skewY($angle * -1);
          transform-origin: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used Jeremy's articles as a starting point. I was trying to have the site as lightweight as possible, thus not using any sass at this point. Will try and see what it gives.

Comment: tried using your code, but failed. The edge of the pseudo element is skewed, but the angle in the design is so that it breaks the whole code. It creates 2 skewed parallelograms not one big block. Any ideas?